# re.finditer has some length but I'm unable to iterate over it

Tags: python, python-re

Following code block works and it seems pretty legit to me. There is `TP` two times in `TP Tutorials Point TP` string so the number of matches should be 2. Also the iteration over this list should work.

```
s = 'TP Tutorials Point TP'

out = re.findall(r'TP', s)

assert len(list(out)) == 2

# this loop will print 2 times matched string
for m in out:
    print(m)
```

But what is going on here?

```
s = 'TP Tutorials Point TP'

out = re.finditer(r'TP', s)

# seems OK so far
assert len(list(out)) == 2

# !!! no output here !!!
for m in out:
    print(m)
```

Why I'm unable to iterate over returned output of `finditer` method? In [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674391/python-locating-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string) it is shown that `finditer` should also work. My python version: 3.8.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.finditer`, as the name implies, returns an iterator. When you use `len(list(out))` you consume the iterator, and from then on it is empty.

You can test it like so:

```
assert len(list(out)) == 2 # First will work
assert len(list(out)) == 2 # Second won't
```

Just remove the `assert` line and you'll receive output:

```
out = re.finditer(r'TP', s)

# We love output :D
for m in out:
    print(m)
```

For more info, you can consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039334/python-iterator-is-empty-after-performing-some-action-on-it).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this line:

```py
assert len(list(out)) == 2
```

Once you execute `list(out)` you exhaust the iterator and then when you try to iterate it again there is nothing left. If you remove that line from your code it works fine:

```py
s = 'TP Tutorials Point TP'

out = re.finditer(r'TP', s)

# lots of output!
for m in out:
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='TP'>
<re.Match object; span=(19, 21), match='TP'>
```